# how to get a distribution using the moment generating function

Tags: probability

we have that X has a normal distribution with mean μ and variance 4.
and we have to get the distribution of $(x-μ)^2/4$.

I tried this: Y=$(x-μ)^2/4$, then $M_{y}(t)=M_{(x-μ)^2/4}=e^{μ^2t}M_{(x^2-2xμ-μ^2)/4}(t)=e^{μ^2t}M_{x^2-2xμ}(t/4)=e^{μ^2t}M_{x^2}(t/4)M_{2xμ}(t/4)$ But im stuck here. what should i do with $M_{x^2}(t/4)$

Comment: Something that may simplify your work is noting that $Z:=(X-\mu)/2$ follows the standard normal distribution and $Y=Z^2$. Then $M_Y(t) = E[e^{tY}]=E[e^{tZ^2}]$ which is the part you were stuck on. Anyway, is there a reason why you need to use the MGF? It is well-known that the square of a standard Gaussian follows a chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom, but I am not sure if you wanted the name of the distribution or the pdf of $Y$ or the MGF of $Y$?

Comment: in the exercise they say to to use the MGF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=(X-\mu)/2$ so that $Y=Z^2$. Then for $t<1/2$, the substitution $u=\sqrt{2(1/2-t)} z$ gives
$$M_Y(t) = E[e^{tZ^2}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{(t-1/2)z^2} \mathop{dz} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1/2-t)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-u^2/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}. $$